# Does Photoshop CS5 Extended have a button for undo more than one times?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

Many software has an undo button for continous backward but I could see such a button in the Photoshop CS5 Extended. Does anyone know how to locate it?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> on a Mac) to step backwards multiple times, you can also select `Edit > Step Backward` from the top menu. And, additionally, you can open the History Window (`Window > History` from the top menu), where you can see every move you have made, and choose to jump to it with your mouse.

On top of that, you can increase the number of Undo/Redos you have in the Preferences > Performance > History States option, if you don't feel you have enough.

Answer (score 3):

In the Adobe range of products `Ctrl+Z` does only take you back one step in the history, pressing it again will redo the last action.

If you want to undo more than just the last action you can use **`CTRL+ALT+Z`**

This should work in atleast the complete adobe CS5 range

Answer (score 1):

On-screen virtual "Undo" button for Photoshop, (all versions).

I wrote an on-screen 'undo' button for Photoshop which you can download from (and read the details regarding) here. . .

http://www.iboxpublishing.com/index_on-screen-undo-button-for-photoshop.php#top_of_news

I wrote it because, while Ctrl-Alt-Z works, if you happen to be working on a Tablet PC screen, (as I am these days), then it is very handy to have a little button you can tap on-screen with the stylus to undo the last action in Photoshop.

The button is tested in WinXP and should work in later versions of Windows, and I've posted both the .exe as well as the script (for AutoHotKey) in which I've written full explanations using language designed for non-programmers, so that people can easily understand how the button works and how you can change it to suit your own needs and tastes.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it's `ALT+CTRL+Z` to step backwards through the history and `SHIFT+CTRL+Z` to step forwards.

If you go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts, you can change them.

Answer (score 0):

Undo/Redo works only one time.

If you want more steps, then open Photoshop CS5, go to *Edit > Preferences > Performance > History States > 100 or more > OK*.

Comment: Yes, that's what the [answer by Johnny](http://superuser.com/questions/193386/does-photoshop-cs5-extended-have-a-button-for-undo-more-than-one-times/283666#283666) already states.